# Script to Loop through array and apply value for DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to loop through a data array and set value for each div element, 
In the line

```
$(".rate-circle").data('value', value);
```

Presently I'm doing this using the code below, however with this approach the value set for my elements is the last element i.e. 35.

```
 var val = [55, 70, 88, 35];//, function (i, l) {
            $("div").each(function () {
                $.each(val, function (index, value) {
                    $(".rate-circle").data('value', value);
                    $(".rate-circle").rateCircle({
                        size: $("#rate-circle-size").val(),
                        lineWidth: 4,
                        fontSize: $("#rate-circle-font-size").val(),
                    });

                });
            });
```

Suggest where am I going wrong, I need to loop through the array and get the values and to set value corresponding to each elements

Comment: `.data()` will set data for all the matched elements...https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/z2wtajud/

Comment: What @rayon-dabre said. Every time you use `.data()` in your inner loop it sets every div.rate-circle 'data-value' attribute to the current value. You might want to give more details of your problem, like an example of the HTML in your page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LoLLp4jc/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny : This solved.. Please include this as a solution, so that I can mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the comments, `$(".rate-circle").data()` will set the same value to all `rate-circle` elements, instead you need to do an index based assignment

```
$(".rate-circle").each(function(idx) {
  $(this).data('value', val[idx]);
}).rateCircle({
  size: $("#rate-circle-size").val(),
  lineWidth: 4,
  fontSize: $("#rate-circle-font-size").val(),
});
```